# Regression model when multiple possible choices

Tags: regression, multinomial-logit, multiple-response

I would like to run a regression on some data I have on high school students and their choice of university they apply to. The data I have gives me characteristics on the students as well as on all the different university programms they could choose. What i want to do is run a regression to understand student's decision in what programs they apply to. The problem is not all student apply to the same number of programs. What type of regression can I do? I am still quite new to econometrics and would appreciate any insights, thank you!